# java string [] array remove special character

Tags: java, string

how to remove `","` in below string specified at `s[0,2]` `location(818001,818002)(151515,151515)` and store again  to string []

```
String[] s = {"818001,818002","121212","151515,151515"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should explain more detailed your problem.

I think what you want is this:

```
s = '(818001,818002)(151515,151515)' //the string you have.
s = s.replace(')(',',').replace('(','').replace(')','');// output "818001,818002,151515,151515"
final_string = s.split(','); //output (4) ["818001", "818002", "151515", "151515"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove a comma (or any other char for that matter) in your String array indices the simplest is to iterate through the array and use [`String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

```
String[] s = {"818001,818002","121212","151515,151515"};
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
  s[i] = s[i].replace(",", "");
}
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(s));  // [818001818002, 121212, 151515151515]
```